# Visual studio docker and kubernetes support

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-container-tools

I am currently using visual studio build an console applocation that has docker support, the problem with this is the application does not seem to start in a external command prompt, but the 
seem to outputting in the internal console window of visual studio, how do i make it execute in a command prompt window?

It seems that the commands it uses forces it to outputted into the dev console window

```
docker exec -i -w "/app" b6375046a58cba92571a425d937a16bd222d87b537af1c1d64ca6b4c845616c9 sh -c ""dotnet" --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2 --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages  "bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/console.dll" | tee /dev/console"
```

how do i the exec command line such that it outputs to a different window?

And is it somehow possible to deploy these containered application into an locally running kubernetes cluster?
Thus utilizing kubernetes services - instead of specifying ip address and etc?

Answer (score -1):

There is no meaining "[different window](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)".

You can run your app in foreground or in detached mode(-d).

```
To start a container in detached mode, you use -d=true or just -d option.
```

In foregroung you shouldn't spesified the -d flag

```
In foreground mode (the default when -d is not specified), docker run can start the process in the container and attach the console to the process’s standard input, output, and standard error
```

And, of course, you can deploy your applications into kubernates cluster. Without any troubles try **minikube** to achieve all what you need.

And kubernets services that is another way to represent your app to the world or other local place.

```
An abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a network service.
```